# Welcome page in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

How can I use a JSF page as welcome file? The `FacesServlet` is mapped on `*.jsf` and the `<welcome-file>` is set to `index.xhtml`. However, it does not show the JSF components. I tried to set the `<welcome-file>` to `index.jsf`, but this results in a HTTP 404 error.

I'm using Tomcat 6.0 and JSF 2.1.

Comment: Your initial question was hard to cipher. I clarified this. I've also removed the second question about implicit navigation, you should actually ask this as another question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just rename `<welcome-file>` entry of `index.xhtml` to `index.jsf` and create an **empty** `index.jsf` file next to `index.xhtml` to fool the container that the file actually exist.

Alternatively, you can also just get rid of the `.jsf` extension altogether and use `.xhtml` all the way. This can be done by changing `<url-pattern>` of `FacesServlet` from `*.jsf` to `*.xhtml`.

Comment: *Just rename <welcome-file> entry of index.xhtml to index.jsf.*

if i rename that entry i will not be able to have access to welcome page through context path(/testjsf), but only through /testjsf/index.jsf

Comment: 1.Fooling the container by creating empty index.jsf works, but is it really good way to solve the problem? 2.Changing <url-pattern> to *.xhtml will not allow me to use any extension that I want.

Comment: 1) It's the easiest way, yes. 2) I don't see why that's a problem. It hides the implementation detail away and also prevents endusers of being able to see JSF source code when they manually change URL in browser address bar from .jsf to .xhtml.

Comment: I'm trying this in Wildfly 8.2.0.Final but it does not seem to be working. When I start the app, it tries to open index.jsf. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Adding it to your welcome-file-list like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Does work, but you'll need Tomcat 7.

Another approach which also works with Tomcat 6 is adding a file called index.jsp with the following contents:

```
<jsp:forward page="/index.jsf"/>
```