# How to redirect root of the project to specific page in a Primefaces+JSF2.0 application using JBOSS 7

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, primefaces, jboss7.x

I have a Primefaces+JSF web site whose home page is 
localhost:81/Mywebapp/login.jsf

I want to redirect the user to that home page if he goes to: localhost:81/Mywebapp/ so he doesnt need to write the complete URL.

How can I do that? I suppose it is some configuration in JBoss

Any help? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Actually it should be in your `web.xml`file, try to put to it's end this entry

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/login.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**EDIT**

I also solved this once by making a new index.jsp like this

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:forward page="/login.jsf" />
</body>
</html>
```

Or put there a html file with this meta

```
 <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content= "0; URL=login.jsf"/>
```

and set one of them as your welcome file. One of these solutions should do the job for you:-)

Comment: Ok, so in your case maybe this one will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015656/welcome-page-in-jsf

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the second answer, the formatting in the comments doesn't really cut it:

```
 <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
...
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>subdir/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Peter's answer should work just fine, but if you're really concerned about the extensions (it doesn't really matter) then just add the places you want mapped under the servlet. This maps *.xhtml, *.jsf and anything under 'subdir/'.

```
If you had a hard file:
- index.xhtml

Myapp/index.xhtml and 
Myapp/index.jsf 
would map to the same file. xhtml is since your default suffix is xhtml
```

I hope this helps, honestly, with Primefaces 2 I'd definitely be using xhtml as that's the spec. With 3 it doesn't matter as much, but I still stay with xhtml as it isn't something I'd normally have on my server.

Best of luck (Petr's forwarding trick isn't a bad idea--it can really help in tough situations)

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this with URL rewriting engines like [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/). You have to activate it in your `web.xml` and then define rewriting rules like this:

```
<url-mapping id="login">
  <pattern value="/login" />
  <view-id value="/legacy/user/login.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

Because you mentioned explicitly `login.jsf` I think it's a good idea to think about including a security framework which is doing this (and many other things) for you. [Seam security](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/SecurityModule) provides typesafe annotations for this:

```
@ViewConfig
public interface SeamPages
{
  static enum Pages0
  {
    @ViewPattern("/jsf/admin/important.xhtml")
    @UrlMapping(pattern="/admin/important")
    @LoginView("/jsf/access/loginRequired.xhtml")
    @AccessDeniedView("/jsf/access/accessDenied.xhtml")
    @RestrictAtPhase(PhaseIdType.RESTORE_VIEW)
    @LoggedIn
    ENUM0;
  }
}
```

This will solve three common requirements:

- The URL `/yourApp/admin/important` will be redirected to the JSF page `/jsf/admin/important.xhtml`.
- If the user is not `@LoggedIn` he will be redirect to `/jsf/access/loginRequired.xhtml`
- IF the user does not have the rights to access the page he will be redirected to `/jsf/access/accessDenied.xhtml`