# JSF page as welcome-file is not found by Tomcat and ends up in 404

Tags: jsf, tomcat, servlets, welcome-file

Well, when i try to access my page in this way:

```
  http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/Odontonew
```

I got the error:

```
type Status report

message /Odontonew/

description The requested resource (/Odontonew/) is not available.
```

But if i try to acces in this way:

```
http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/Odontonew/index.jon
```

This works fine. So i have sure my problem is in web.xml but i don't know where, see bellow my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID">
    <display-name>Odontonew</display-name>
    <!-- Configuracao do Spring -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
    <!-- Configuracao DO JSF -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jon</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Servlet para Direcionar imagens -->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>br.com.odontonew.util.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pictures/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jon</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>  
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
    <param-value>afterwork</param-value>  
    </context-param>

    <context-param>   
<param-name>com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd</param-name>   
<param-value>false</param-value>   
</context-param>

<context-param>
 <param-name>pictureDirectory</param-name>
 <param-value>${user.home}/webapp/Odontonew/pictures/</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
<param-value>51200</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
<param-value>${user.home}/webapp/Odontonew/tmp/</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

In root folder of my project i have the page "index.xhtml", but i wanna access the project with the path: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/Odontonew (without the index.jon or index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused because your `<welcome-file>index.jon</welcome-file>` does not physically exist in the root folder. There's only an `index.xhtml`. When a folder is being requested in the URL like `/`, then the servletcontainer will first check if the physical file as specified in `<welcome-file>` is present, so that it can decide whether to continue the request or return a 404. The servletcontainer does at that point not take the mappings of any registered servlets into account. In your particular case, `index.jon` is a virtual URL and does not represent a physically existing file, hence the 404.

You can solve this by placing an empty but physically existing `index.jon` file next to `index.xhtml` file in the same folder. This way you fool the servletcontainer that the `index.jon` really exists and then it will continue the request which will ultimately hit the `FacesServlet` who serves the `index.xhtml`.

An alternative is to change the `FacesServlet` URL pattern of `*.jon` to `*.xhtml` so that you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs. If you really need it to be `*.jon` for some unclear reason, then again another alternative is to rename the physical file from `index.xhtml` to `index.jon` and set `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` context parameter to `.jon`.

Note that the concrete problem is essentially unrelated to JSF. It's related to basic servlets. You'd have exactly the same problem when using a different kind of servlet.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/3008504#3008504)

Comment: Cool, but why when i tried put URL Pattern of "*.jon" and welcome-file "index.html" didn't work ? I got a blank page only with character without JSF TAGS.

Comment: Apparently you didn't understood the answer. You're mixing 2 solutions. Choose the one or the other (there are 3 in my answer, separated by "alternative" which is IMO a clear English word).

Comment: thanks @BalusC, i already understood the problem with your answer and reading another articles about this.

Comment: You're welcome. As answered, if you want to stick to URL pattern of `*.jon`, then you should be creating a physically existing but empty `index.jon` file. Exactly as stated in 2nd paragraph of the answer. You should **not** be changing the `<welcome-file>` to `index.html` as you unexpectedly did as per your first comment (that part indicates the misunderstanding). If you really want to change the `<welcome-file>` to `index.html`, then you should be changing the URL pattern to `*.html` as well and re-apply the answer as if it were `*.jon`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [in many answers on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015656/welcome-page-in-jsf), welcome file entry represents *a physical file path relative to the current URL path ending with `/`*. As you most plausibly don't have any index.jon file in your root directory, you get the error.

So, you can either create a physical file index.jon in you root folder (don't worry, the one rendered will be index.xhtml), or simply switch to `*.xhtml` URL pattern to get rid of this unnecessary stuff altogether.